# Can I use Object.assign to create a "class"

Tags: javascript

I currently have this bit of code here:

```
let loginWindow = Object.assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  window: null,
  create: () => {
    // Load LoginWindow Settings
    Settings.get("loginWindowState")
    .then((state) => {
      if (state === undefined) state = {};
      loginWindow.window = new BrowserWindow({
        x: state.x || 0,
        y: state.y || 0,
        width: state.width || 600,
        height: state.height || 700,
        frame: false,
        show: false
      });
      if (_.isEmpty(state)) {
        loginWindow.window.center();
      }
      if (state.maximized) {
        loginWindow.window.maximize();
      }
      loginWindow.window.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/../views/index.html`);
      loginWindow.window.on('closed', () => { loginWindow.window = null; });
      loginWindow.window.on('ready-to-show', () => loginWindow.window.show());
      loginWindow.window.on('move', rememberWindowState);
      loginWindow.window.on('resize', rememberWindowState);
      loginWindow.window.on('maximize', rememberWindowState);
      loginWindow.window.on('unmaximize', rememberWindowState);
    });
    loginWindow.emit("created");
  },
  close: () => {
    loginWindow.window.close();
  }
});
```

I'm using it to control windows in my `Electron` project, though I seem to be misunderstanding its construction.

There is no `this` or at least it returns undefined at run time, also I can not do say

`loginWindow.emit("created")` from within its self, but if I was to create the object and do it from outside it would work just fine

I would like to use the event emitter on creation but instead I've replaced `loginWindow.emit("created");`

with

`return Promise.resolve(true);`

and now I know when it's done being created, but I feel like I should be able to use an event emitter in its place instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` was really not designed for this purpose. And also, arrow functions does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. That's why it returns `undefined` in your case. Anyway, here is my recommending approach.

```
let loginWindow = new class extends EventEmitter{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.window = null;
  }
  create(){
    // Load LoginWindow Settings
    Settings.get("loginWindowState")
    .then((state) => {
      if (state === undefined) state = {};
      loginWindow.window = new BrowserWindow({
        x: state.x || 0,
        y: state.y || 0,
        width: state.width || 600,
        height: state.height || 700,
        frame: false,
        show: false
      });
      if (_.isEmpty(state)) {
        this.window.center();
      }
      if (state.maximized) {
        this.window.maximize();
      }
      this.window.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/../views/index.html`);
      this.window.on('closed', () => { loginWindow.window = null; });
      this.window.on('ready-to-show', () => loginWindow.window.show());
      this.window.on('move', rememberWindowState);
      this.window.on('resize', rememberWindowState);
      this.window.on('maximize', rememberWindowState);
      this.window.on('unmaximize', rememberWindowState);
    });
    this.emit("created");
  }
  close(){
    this.window.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I would need to instantiate every new loginWindow with `new` then call `blah.create`? I'm trying to avoid using `new` as I don't really feel I need to use it for this purpose